# Using Fubini's theorem to show that $\int_0^T\int_0^{\tau}\xi(t)dtd\tau=\int_0^T(T-t)\xi(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Using Fubini's theorem we have,

$$  \int_0^T\int_0^{\tau}\xi(t)dtd\tau=\int_0^T(T-t)\xi(t)dt\quad\forall \xi\in L_1(0,T)$$

with $t\in(0,\tau)$, $\tau\in(0,T)$

Can anybody give a hint?

Comment: For the moment, set $T =1$ and recall cal 3.

Comment: Are you sure about the bounds ? $\tau$ does not appear in the final answer, this is abnormal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's been integrated out

Comment: @CalvinKhor: as written, the domain is a rectangle of area $T\tau$ and the integral is $T\tau\bar\xi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $\tau \in [0,T],\ t ∈ [0,\tau]$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: who knows, the formula is ambiguous.

Comment: @CalvinKhor    Yes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is ambiguous? The integral on the LHS is on the domain $0<t<\tau<T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the indicator function

$$1_{(t \leqslant \tau)}(t,\tau)= \begin{cases}1, \,\, t \leqslant \tau \\0, \,\,t> \tau  \end{cases},$$

we can expand the region of integration to the rectangle $[0,T] \times [0,T]$:

$$\int_0^T\int_0^{\tau}\xi(t) \, dt \,d\tau = \int_0^T\int_0^{T}\xi(t) 1_{(t \leqslant \tau)}\, dt \,d\tau .$$

Apply Fubini' s theorem to interchange the order of integration, yielding

$$\begin{align}\int_0^T\int_0^{\tau}\xi(t) \, dt \,d\tau &= \int_0^T\int_0^{T}\xi(t) 1_{(t \leqslant \tau)}\, d\tau \,dt \\ &=  \int_0^T\int_t^{T} \xi(t)\, d\tau \,dt \\ &= \int_0^T\xi(t)(T-t) \, dt.\end{align}$$